# Proving that $\sup(S+T)=\sup(S)+\sup(T)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S$ and $T$ be nonempty sets of real numbers and define
>   $$S+T = \{s+t| s \in S, t \in T\}$$
>   show that $\sup(S+T)=\sup(S)+\sup(T)$ if S and T are bounded above.

I am thinking about a proof by contradiction such as:

- Let's suppose that $\sup(S+T) \neq \sup(S) +\sup(T)$, then either $\sup(S+T) > \sup(S) +\sup(T)$  OR  $\sup(S+T) < \sup(S) +\sup(T)$
- If $$\sup(S+T) > \sup(S) +\sup(T)$$
  $$ \sup(S+T) -2\epsilon > \sup(S) -\epsilon +\sup(T) -\epsilon $$
  with $\epsilon >0$
- $ \exists x_3 \in(S+T)$ , $ \exists x_2 \in S$ , $ \exists x_1 \in T$ such that

$$ x_3 >\sup(S+T) -2\epsilon > x_1 + x_2> \sup(S) -\epsilon +\sup(T) -\epsilon $$
(using the property of supremum)  **statement A**

- Also, if $x_2 \in S$ and $x_1 \in T$, then $ x_2,x_1 \in (S+T)$

and, as $x_3 > x_2+x_1$ , using the theorem of supremum, $x_2+x_1 > \sup(S+T)- 2\epsilon$ **statement B**

- However, statement B is in contradiction with statement A. Therefore $\sup(S+T)$ cannot be greater  to $\sup(S) +\sup(T)$

I will then continue to the second case.

Is there a more efficient approach? am I going in the right direction?

Any input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The proof should work like this, even though it is a little complicated. Using the same ideas, you could make a direct proof as follows:
Define $s := \sup(S) + \sup(T)$. Now show that $x \leq s$ for every $x \in S + T$ (that should be rather fast).
Next, show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $x  \in S + T$ such that $s-x < \epsilon$. Here, your idea with $x_1 \in S$ and $x_2 \in T$ can be applied. Take both together to conclude that $s = \sup(S + T)$.